# android microphone intent

Tags: android, android-intent, microphone

how can i start this activity with this intent without having the screen switch from my current activity?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
startActivityForResult(intent, 444);
```

Comment: What do you consider "the android microphone intent" to be? That term is not part of standard Android, so you will need to provide us with your definition.